# Making a question with the verb "to go"

Tags: questions, construction

I remember reading or hearing that English is a very unusual language, almost unique, in using the verb "to go" to create a question. (Are you going to see the play? Are you going to drink that coffee?) Most languages would do something a lot simpler such as changing word order (See you the play? Drink you that coffee?). If you think about it, unless you've grown up with it all your life, it is a strange construction.

So my question (out of curiosity) is: Am I correct in what I said above? If so, can someone point me to an article online where I can read some more about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's unique at all. That formulation is almost exactly the same as in French:

> Tu vas voir le spectacle?
>   Tu vas boire ce café?

It's just a form of the immediate future tense, which exists in a number of languages.

Comment: I was thinking though that we italians don't have such construction... I'm not sure about other European/Eastern-European/North-European languages since I don't know them good enough...

Comment: Hmmm. I wonder if there is something peculiar in this construction though. 1. Maybe what's unusual about English is the required auxiliary verb in a closed question: *He goes to class on Fridays* is fine, but *Goes he to class on Fridays?* is wrong. You would say, *Does he go to class on Fridays?* 2. Or maybe the unusual thing is that in English, *go + infinitive* only works with *go* in the progressive: *I am going to throttle you* is correct, but not *I go to throttle you* ...which I think is how you would say it in Spanish.

Answer (score 3):

[Going-to future](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Going-to_future) is a complete article about what you asked for.

Summary:

**"Usage"**
Going-to future is a term used to describe an English sentence structure referring to the future, making use of the verb phrase to be going to.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Going-to_future) The verb "go" can also be used to indicate the future in some other languages.

**"Origin"**
The original construction involved physical movement with an intention, such as

> I am going [outside] to harvest the
>   crop.

The location later became unnecessary, and the expression was reinterpreted to represent a near future.

**"Structure"**
  The going to future is formed as subject + be (in the proper form for the subject) + going to + verb + any other information.

Same structure in French, Spanish and Creoles.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I think I asked the wrong question! Everyone else, please ignore this or perhaps someone with enough privaledge can close it.

Comment: No problem, I've gained a privilege for this answer. ;)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure it's exactly unique.

French has a similar construction:

> Qu'est-ce que tu **vas manger**?

Same goes for Spanish:

> ¿Qué **vas a comer**?

Comment: And also Norwegian has same structure.

Comment: ...guess I was mistaken?

Comment: @Boob: Can you write it highlighting the "going to + verb" part? :D thanks. @Richard: yeah eheh :D no worries, it's a nice question, I'll upvote you.

Comment: Yes, I think my memory was wrong here. I think I meant "do" - I'll ask the question again

Comment: jeg **kommer til å** gå på universitetet.

Comment: @Boob: Thanks +1 :D, by the way, I didn't say it, but you are free to edit it personally! This site allows it (if you didn't know already). :) @Richard Ok!